# How to generate a table of figures

Tags: tables, subfloats

How to generate a table of figures like this example below:
 [image]

Comment: Do they all have the same size?

Comment: @Bernard all the figures are the same size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a table of figures like this one you can use the package `booktabs`, like this:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\dummyfigure}{\tikz \fill [NavyBlue] (0,0) rectangle node [black] {Figure} (2,2);}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
           \toprule
            Nr. & a & b & c & d \\
            \midrule
            1 & \dummyfigure & \dummyfigure & \dummyfigure & \dummyfigure \\
            2 & \dummyfigure & \dummyfigure & \dummyfigure & \dummyfigure \\
            3 & \dummyfigure & \dummyfigure & \dummyfigure & \dummyfigure \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Table of figures}
        \label{tbl:table_of_figures}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

But, as you can see in the figure below, the text in the first column will not be vertically aligned.

[image: Table of figures]

In order to do this, you need to use the `array` package and create a new column type:

```latex
    \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
```

Then, use this new column type for the columns containing the figures, like this:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\dummyfigure}{\tikz \fill [NavyBlue] (0,0) rectangle node [black] {Figure} (2,2);}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cM{20mm}M{20mm}M{20mm}M{20mm}}
           \toprule
            Nr. & a & b & c & d \\
            \midrule
            1 & \dummyfigure & \dummyfigure & \dummyfigure & \dummyfigure \\
            2 & \dummyfigure & \dummyfigure & \dummyfigure & \dummyfigure \\
            3 & \dummyfigure & \dummyfigure & \dummyfigure & \dummyfigure \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Table of figures}
        \label{tbl:table_of_figures}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table of figures]

Comment: how to decrease the distance between the column Nr. and column a?

Comment: @rayallen you can add what you want between columns with `@{}`, so you can increase/decrease the space between them with `@{\hspace{1mm}}`. In your case, you need to replace the column types, for example, with: `\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{1mm}}M{20mm}M{20mm}M{20mm}M{20mm}}`

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that all figures could be `6em` wide, this can be done using `booktabs` in a normal `tabular` environment.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,array}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\addpic}{\includegraphics[width=6em]{example-image}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{6em}}
\begin{table}\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{l*4{C}@{}}
\toprule
Nr. & a & b & c & d \\ 
\midrule
1 & \addpic & \addpic & \addpic & \addpic \\ 
2 & \addpic & \addpic & \addpic & \addpic \\ 
3 & \addpic & \addpic & \addpic & \addpic \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how to make the distance between column a and b smaller than others

Comment: @rayallen - You can explicitly specify column spacing as you wish, e.g., `{lC@{\hspace{4pt}}CCC@{}}`. This `4pt` can be any length.