# generating a table of Figures with labels below the figures

Tags: tables, floats, subfig

I would like to generate a table of Figures. An excellent example is [How to generate a table of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310807/how-to-generate-a-table-of-figures).
Which I have accomplished, however now I would like to add labels below each figure (a), (b)....... so that I can refer to them in the text. This could be accomplished by [Insert multiple figures in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/insert-multiple-figures-in-latex), however, in my case I would like the x labels and y labels to be present (as shown in the figure below). Additionally, I would like the y axis labels to be rotated 90 degrees.

[image]

Comment: Please provide the code of your table shown. Your link does only provide similar tables. What  are x labels and y labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table taken from the accepted answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/310820/224762):

You need `\usepackage{caption}` and can use `\caption*{...}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\dummyfigure}{\tikz \fill [NavyBlue] (0,0) rectangle node [black] {Figure} (2,2);}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cM{20mm}M{20mm}M{20mm}M{20mm}}
            \toprule
            Nr. & Case 1 & Case 2 & Case 3 & Case 4 \\
            \midrule
            \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Parameter 1} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(a)}\label{a} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(b)}\label{b} & \dummyfigure  \caption*{(c)}\label{c}& \dummyfigure \caption*{(d)}\label{d}\\
            \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Parameter 2} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(e)}\label{e} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(f)}\label{f} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(g)}\label{g} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(h)}\label{h} \\
            \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Parameter 3} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(i)}\label{i} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(j)}\label{j} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(k)}\label{k} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(l)}\label{l}\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Table of figures}
        \label{tbl:table_of_figures}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The subfigure package is considered deprecated for quite a while now. Using subfig or subcaption would be better.

Comment: @leandriis I don´t know why it was there. I did not need it for the table.

Answer (score 2):

For sub captions you can use `subfloat` environment as defined in `subfig` or in `subcaption` version 2.3 package. For rotating of contents in the first row can be used `rotating` and `makecell` packages, for table is handy to use (new) `tabularray` package.

In MWE are for images used `example-image-duck` provided in the `graphicx` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption} % version 1.3
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}    
\usepackage{makecell}   
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, counter, varwidth}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{PARAMETERS 3}    % from makecell
\begin{tblr}{colspec = { Q[h] *{4}{Q[c,m, wd=35mm]}},
             colsep  = 3pt,
             cell{2-Z}{1} = {cmd=\rotcell, font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             measure=vbox
            }
    \toprule
Nr. & Case 1    & Case 2    & Case 3    & Case 4    \\
    \midrule
PARAMETERS 1
    & \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
        & \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
            & \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
                & \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}     \\
PARAMETERS 2
    & \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
        & \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
            & \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
                & \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}     \\
PARAMETERS 3
    & \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
        & \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
            & \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
                & \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{Table of figures}
\label{tbl:table_of_figures}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]